Checkbox array gets undefined array key error when submitted
I'm making a form with multiple checkboxes for each product category. However, when I submit the form, my php file doesn't get the contents of the array.
This is the div where the checkboxes are, it is enclosed in a form tag.
<div class="category-list">
    <div class="category-item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="electronics"
            id="electronicsCheckbox">
        <label for="">Electronics</label>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="clothing" id="clothingCheckbox">
        <label for="">Clothing & Apparel</label>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="jewelry" id="jewelryCheckbox">
        <label for="">Jewelry & Accessories</label>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="food" id="foodCheckbox">
        <label for="">Food</label>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="beverages" id="beveragesCheckbox">
        <label for="">Beverages</label>
    </div>
</div>

this is my php file for handling the form submission
<?php
session_start();
require "../config/dbconn.php";

$userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
$productName = $_POST['productName'];
$productDescription = $_POST['productDesc'];
$productQuantity = $_POST['productQty'];

$variations = $_POST['variationsData'];
$arrayOfVariations = json_decode($variations, true);
$paymentMethods = $_POST['paymentMethod'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO products (productSellerID, productName, productDesc) VALUES ('$userID', '$productName', '$productDescription')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if ($result) {
    if (isset($_POST['categories'])) {
        $categories = $_POST['categories'];
        print_r($categories);
    } else {
        echo "No array found.";
    }
}

?>

I already tried placing a hidden input tag for the array, but it doesn't work.
Edit: "No array found." is being printed so that means the else if condition is met. And yes, I'll be dealing with the prepared statements later on when I figure this bug out.

Checkboxes only cause an entry in the form submission data set, if they were checked. So if none of them was checked, then $_POST['categories'] won't be set either. But it looks like you are explicitly checking for that with isset, before you access it the first time - so not sure, what exact error you are getting here in regard to this? Please clarify.

(And that this really needs something done about SQL injection, is clear, I hope? You should really be using prepared statements in this day and age.)

The most likely reason for it going into the else and printing "array not found" is if none of the checkboxes were ticked on the form, as CBroe said. Either that, or possibly the checkboxes aren't actually inside the form? We can't  see from the HTML you've posted. Have you used the browser's Developer Tools to check the payload of the form when you submit it? (You can see it in the Network tool when you submit the form - click on the POST request to your PHP script, and then the payload tab within that)

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your script is vulnerable to SQL Injection Attack. Even if you are escaping variables, its not safe! You should always use prepared statements and parameterized queries in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating variables into the query.
